# How change htmllabel background color width on xamarin?

Tags: html, css, xamarin, label

I want to set the width of the htmllabel text background color in xamarin, but it covers the color as long as the text's length. How can I cover the whole background?I want the red area to be as wide as the turquoise color in the back.

[image]

I'm sending html code from the service like this

```
Imd.DR = (d.OncelikID != (int)Sabitler.Oncelik.Yuksek) ? Fonksiyonlar.ModulDurumVer(d.DurumID ?? 0).Adi : "<span style=\"display:block; text-align:center; background-color:#ff0000; margin:auto; \">"
                                  + Fonksiyonlar.ModulDurumVer(d.DurumID ?? 0).Adi  + "<span>";
```

this is my xaml code in xamarin:

```
<htmlLabel:HtmlLabel Text="{Binding DR}" BackgroundColor="#b2e8e7" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"   />
```

Here is the entire xaml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OzelKalem.Views.ListeContentViews.AramaListeContent"
             xmlns:htmlLabel="clr-namespace:LabelHtml.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=OzelKalem"
                     xmlns:Prl="clr-namespace:Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;assembly=Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh"
               xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OzelKalem.Models"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             BackgroundColor="#00b3ae"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
    <ContentView.Content>


        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0" RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Button x:Name="Geri"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="TarihDegistir" CommandParameter="-1" ContentLayout="Top,5" BackgroundColor="#edebeb"  BorderColor="#cccccc" BorderWidth="1" 
                        ImageSource="{local:ResourceResimExt ResourceId=OzelKalem.Content.images.leftarrow.png }"  WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" />
                    <Label Text="" x:Name="lbl_GosterimTurID" IsVisible="False"></Label>
                    <Label Text="" x:Name="lbl_VarsayilanTarih" IsVisible="False"></Label>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label Text="Saat" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="lbl_Tarih" VerticalOptions="Center"  FontSize="10" HeightRequest="8" Margin="0" />
                        <Label Text="Saat" HorizontalOptions="Center" x:Name="lbl_GunTarih" VerticalOptions="Center"   FontSize="10" HeightRequest="8" Margin="0"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Button x:Name="ileri" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center"   Clicked="TarihDegistir" CommandParameter="1" ContentLayout="Top,5"  BackgroundColor="#edebeb"  BorderColor="#cccccc" BorderWidth="1" 
                        ImageSource="{local:ResourceResimExt ResourceId=OzelKalem.Content.images.rightarrow.png }"  WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"  />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
          
            <Grid Grid.Row="2"  RowSpacing="0" Margin="10,0,10,0" >

                <Prl:PullToRefreshLayout IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" BackgroundColor="White" RefreshBackgroundColor="White"  x:Name="plr_Arama" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                    <ScrollView>
                        <StackLayout  x:Name="stc_Arama" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Icerik}" BackgroundColor="White" IsTabStop="True"   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackLayout >
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="arama_Secim"   />
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Grid BackgroundColor="#0070c0" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1" Padding="0,0,0,1" VerticalOptions="Start">
                                            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{OnIdiom 
                                                Phone= {OnPlatform iOS=4*, Android=3*},
                                                Tablet= {OnPlatform iOS=2*, Android=2*}}">
                                                    </ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{OnIdiom 
                                                Phone= {OnPlatform iOS=6*, Android=5*},
                                                Tablet= {OnPlatform iOS=6*, Android=6*}}">
                                                    </ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{OnIdiom 
                                                Phone= {OnPlatform iOS=6*, Android=5*},
                                                Tablet= {OnPlatform iOS=6*, Android=6*}}">
                                                    </ColumnDefinition>
                                           
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ID}" IsVisible="False" x:Name="ID" FontSize="10"  />

                                                <ContentView  Grid.Column="0">
                                                    <StackLayout >
                                            
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding GSaat}"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="10" />
                                                        
                                                        <ContentView BackgroundColor="#00b3ae" >
                                                            <ContentView BackgroundColor="White"  Margin="0,1,0,0" Padding="1">
                                                                <htmlLabel:HtmlLabel  Text="{Binding DR}" BackgroundColor="#b2e8e7" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"   />
                                                            </ContentView>
                                                        </ContentView>
                                                        <Image Source="{local:ResourceResimExt ResourceId=OzelKalem.Content.images.modultalimat.png }" x:Name="img_Logo"   IsVisible="{Binding isTalimatSurecli,Converter={local:DegerKontrolkExtyeni}}" WidthRequest="15" HeightRequest="15"></Image>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </ContentView>
                                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                                                    <!--<Label Text="{Binding KListe,Converter={local:KatilimciListeModel}}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap" FontSize="12" />-->
                                                    <htmlLabel:HtmlLabel Text="{Binding KListe,Converter={local:KatilimciListeExt}}" FontSize="10" />
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding SListe,Converter={local:SurecListeExt}}" FontAttributes="Bold"   FontSize="8"  />
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout Grid.Column="2"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <htmlLabel:HtmlLabel Text="{Binding Ack}"    Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="10"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                                    <!--<Label Text="{Binding Ack}"   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />-->

                                                    <Label Text="{Binding YKA}"  TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="10" FontAttributes="Bold"  IsVisible="{Binding YKA,Converter={local:DegerKontrolkExt}}" MinimumWidthRequest="40" />
                                                 
                                                       
                                                        <!--<Label Text="{Binding YKA}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="12" /-->
                                                
                                                </StackLayout>
                                               
                                           

                                        </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>


                    </ScrollView>

                </Prl:PullToRefreshLayout>
    </Grid>
        </Grid>



    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: You need to set HorizontalOptions

Comment: Try to add `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` to your htmllabel.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the [HorizontalOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.view.horizontaloptions#xamarin-forms-view-horizontaloptions) to `Fill`, it will ensure that the [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.view?view=xamarin-forms) fills the width of its parent layout.

You can try below:

```
HorizontalOptions="Fill"
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. The result is the same. I added HorizontalOptions="Fill"

Comment: @BüşraGüler Thanks for the update, can you help add all the xaml code to your post?

Comment: I added the complete xaml code

Comment: Have you had a chance to review it, I wonder why it doesn't cover the background somehow?

Comment: Yes, you should set the `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` in your label  `<htmlLabel:HtmlLabel Text="{Binding DR}"   HorizontalOptions="Fill" />`

Comment: Just adding HorizontalOptions="Fill" wasn't enough. I changed the background color of the ContentView, which is white, and changed the color of the contentview above. Then I wanted to change the color of the text instead of the background color.

Answer (score 0):

this is the last situation

[image]

I'm sending html code from the service like this:

```
 Imd.DR = (d.OncelikID != (int)Sabitler.Oncelik.Yuksek) ? Fonksiyonlar.ModulDurumVer(d.DurumID ?? 0).Adi : "<div style=\"background-color:#ff9688; margin:0; display:block; width:100%;\">"
                                  + Fonksiyonlar.ModulDurumVer(d.DurumID ?? 0).Adi  + "</div>";
```

my xmal code:

```
<ContentView BackgroundColor="#00b3ae"  >
             <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="White"  Margin="0,1,0,0" Padding="1">
             <htmlLabel:HtmlLabel Text="{Binding DR}"   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" BackgroundColor="#b2e8e7" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10"/>
             </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: how can the text background be red in the margins?